# How to pass multiple values to custom fields using campaign monitor API

Tags: php, api

According to campaign monitor's sample code, values of custom fields can be passed like this when adding a new subscriber

```
<?php 
    require_once '../../csrest_subscribers.php';

    $wrap = new CS_REST_Subscribers('Your list ID', 'Your API Key');
    $result = $wrap->add(array(
      'EmailAddress' => 'Subscriber email',
      'Name' => 'Subscriber name',
      'CustomFields' => array(
          array(
               'Key' => 'Field Key',
               'Value' => 'Field Value'
               )
        ),
       'Resubscribe' => true
    ));
?>
```

Now the above code works fine if I pass a single vale to the CustomFields element but does not work when i try to pass mulitple values. I have searched the API documentation but cant find any information on how to pass mulitple values to a single custom field key.

What I want to be able to do is something along this line

```
'CustomFields' => array(
     array(
           'Key' => 'Field Key',
           'Value' => 'Value 1, Value2'
           //OR 'Value' => array('value1', 'value2')
           )
    ),
```

please notice how i have passed two values using comma as a delimiter. Please does anybody know how to do what i am trying to achieve or know whether this is supported by campaign monitor API or not. Any info on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me.You need to add campaign monitor class files in you project folder and use valid list id and api key.You can find you api key from **manage account** link and list id from click on **(change name/type)** below list title.

You need to create **"Custom fields"**(on right sidebar) from your **listid**. Ex(Subject,Phone Number,Suburb,Message etc).

When you **export** the subscribers list, then you can find the custom filed data.

Please wait some time to see in you list.

```
require_once 'csrest_subscribers.php';


$name = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['your-tel'];
$suburb = $_POST['your-suburb'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];


$wrap = new CS_REST_Subscribers('Your list ID', 'Your API Key');
$result = $wrap->add(array(
    'EmailAddress' => $email,
    'Name' => $name,
    'CustomFields' => array(
        array(
            'Key' => "Subject",
            'Value' => $subject
        ),
        array(
            'Key' => "Phone Number",
            'Value' => $phone
        ),
        array(
            'Key' => "Suburb",
            'Value' => $suburb
        ),
        array(
            'Key' => "Message",
            'Value' => $message
        )
    ), 
    'Resubscribe' => true
));

echo "Result of POST /api/v3/subscribers/{list id}.{format}\n<br />";
if($result->was_successful()) {
    echo "Subscribed with code ".$result->http_status_code;
} else {
    echo 'Failed with code '.$result->http_status_code."\n<br /><pre>";
    var_dump($result->response);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Answer (score -2):

`Please does anybody know how to do what i am trying to achieve or know whether this is supported by campaign monitor API or not`

Based by their [Reference](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/api/subscribers/#adding_a_subscriber), you should can send something like

```
'CustomFields' => array(
 array(
       'Key' => 'Field Key 1',
       'Value' => 'Value 1'
       ),
 array(
       'Key' => 'Field Key 2',
       'Value' => 'Value 2'
       ),
),
```

But if you need to store an array value on that, i think you can "cheated" it by using serialized data in your value, then you can unserialize the returned data (when you perform GET) to get your array back.